# Why does my grid have 3 columns when I've set grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); gap: 1.5rem;">
    <div class="card">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

[image: chrome's DevTools Computed tab showing three columns even though it is set to repeat(2, 1fr)]

Comment: Looks like there's other code involved. Can you post all relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was I had an extra div at the bottom of the grid that was too wide and creating the odd behaviour. So if you have a similar problem check all your children of grid.

Comment: THANK YOU! There was a pesky inconspicuous child element _all the way_ at the end, and that was indeed causing the problem. Here, have my upvote, this saved me 

Comment: THANKS!  This is also prompted me to look in the correct place.  The issue for me was an item in the grid with a larger span than the grid allowed for.